# Where on Comet 67P is the Philae lander?

Tags: philae

My institute has a 3D printed model of Comet 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko in its common room. Someone recently asked where the Philae lander is located. I know that [it's been found](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Rosetta/Philae_found) but I can't point to it on the model, because that ESA page only has close-ups of its location, not a broad view showing where the lander is located in relation to the comet as a whole. Does such a view exist?

It would be nice to know also where it first touched down and where it bounced before coming to rest, if those things are known.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Philae lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae_(spacecraft))'s *last observed location* in September 2016 is on the comets smaller lobe, settling there after a few bounces following a 2 hour "flight". It is reasonable to assume that it is still there or nearby, but [67P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/67P/Churyumov%E2%80%93Gerasimenko) is a comet, and even though it does not get closer than 1.24 AU from the Sun, there is always a possibility that it might have moved due to some surface event, since the local gravity is only about 1E-04 that of Earth's.

The visual confirmation came just 2 weeks prior to rosetta's own comet landing date. You can find more pictures and a detailed description of Philae's adventures on the Rosetta blogpost dated Sept-05-2016 [Philae Found!](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2016/09/05/philae-found/), which is also the source of the image below.

> The images were taken on 2 September by the OSIRIS narrow-angle camera as the orbiter came within 2.7 km of the surface and clearly show the main body of the lander, along with two of its three legs.
>
> The images also provide proof of Philae’s orientation, making it clear why establishing communications was so difficult following its landing on 12 November 2014.
>
> [...]
>
> Philae was last (previously) seen when it first touched down at Agilkia, bounced and then flew for another two hours before ending up at a location later named Abydos, on the comet’s smaller lobe.

[image: ESA pic]

In the comments, Uwe posted a link with a [detailed explanation of how the lander was found](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2016/09/28/the-story-behind-finding-philae/), which includes a diagram that very clearly shows the location of the site:

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Double check if the edits are OK?

Comment: More details about finding Philae [here](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2016/09/28/the-story-behind-finding-philae/).

Comment: @Uwe that article is *great!* What an amazing "detective" story.

Comment: @Uwe could you post that as an answer, perhaps including the graphic from that article as an image? That image answers my question.

Comment: @drandrul I've seen the image you posted before - in fact, I linked to it in the question - but the issue is that it doesn't show whereabouts on the smaller lobe the site is located. I can't tell where the zoomed-in photos are in relation to the zoomed-out one.

Comment: The picture got compressed so the red fades away, i have highlighted it in this picture [here](https://imgur.com/uePG8WR)

Comment: Ah I see, there are some pinkish pixels now you come to mention it!

Comment: @Uwe I've edited your link into this answer, along with the diagram. If you or drandul doesn't like this feel free to edit it out - if the edit gets accepted I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Nathaniel: It is OK for me that you included the image to the answer. I have not learned how to include images into answers yet. I should read the explanation and try it.

Comment: There is a difference in the indicated position between these two pictures [a](https://imgur.com/uePG8WR) and [b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ShwZ.jpg).